# Brightness keys (fn5 and fn6) not working

Tags: keyboard

Just installed the newest elementary os on my asus ux305, and all the fn keys but the brightness dont, i already tried every solution i found on the internet with no positive solution.

Comment: Can you confirm they are not working _only_ in elementary?

Comment: Can you also mention what you HAVE tried.